# Dynamically slice a dataframe using Matplotlib dropdown widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I have the following code adapted from [this blog](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/#:%7E:text=for%20some%20examples.-,Putting%20widgets%20to%20use,-In%20the%20next) to slice a dataframe based on the selected values of two dropdown widgets, then updated the graph with the new data.

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
%matplotlib widget

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'],
                   'EUR': [0.636805, 0.637249, 0.637676, 0.642802, 0.643764],
                   'JPY': [89.564402, 89.217571, 88.275751, 89.122584, 90.270398], 
                   'USD': [0.680616, 0.680714, 0.676402, 0.681486, 0.681911]
                    })

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

output = widgets.Output()

x = df[['Date', 'USD']]

with output:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(6, 4))
    line, = ax.plot(x['Date'], x['USD'])

dropdown_1 = widgets.Dropdown(
    value=pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01'), 
    options=df['Date'].values, 
    description='Start Date',
)

dropdown_2 = widgets.Dropdown(
    value=pd.to_datetime('2023-01-05'), 
    options=df['Date'].values,     
    description='End Date',
)     

def update_graph(start, end):
    # Find the locations of the new dates obtained from the dropdowns
    start_idx = x.index[x['Date'] == start.new].tolist()[0]
    end_idx = x.index[x['Date'] == end.new].tolist()[0]
    # Dynamically change the data to plot
    line.set_data(x[start_idx:end_idx])  
    fig.canvas.draw()

dropdown_1.observe(update_graph, 'value')
dropdown_2.observe(update_graph, 'value')
widgets.VBox([dropdown_1, dropdown_2])
```

However, the graph didn't update with the new data when I changed the values of the dropdown widgets.

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong?